# JQuery Validation showing "Please enter a multiple of 0.01" on HTML number textbox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 project which uses the built-in jQuery validation library.

I have declared a textbox that is to accept a number that must be to two decimal places:

```
@Html.TextBox("", Model, new
{
    @class = "form-control",
    type ="number",
    placeholder ="0.00",
    step = "0.01"
})
```

When the page renders, I can't get this field to pass validation, no matter what I enter in the field, e.g. "100.22".

The validation error is:

> "Please enter a multiple of 0.01".

Any ideas why this would happen?

I'm also using FluentValidation, but I've only used a `NotEmpty()` and `GreaterThan(0)` validation.

Comment: Try entering numbers with "," instead of "."

Comment: oh! That's it :) Feel free to stick that it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem must be related with the syntax. Try entering the numbers with "," instead of "."